# Bloomberg Excel Add-In find name changes

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I got a question regarding the Bloomberg Add in. I am working with some security funds and I Need Information on past changes. like e.g. splits. I could find everything I Need, but some funds changed their Name/ Identifier in the Past like HYPECOT LX. It changed from Activest EcoFund to Pioneer Funds. And also the number changed. I can not find a field, that gives me back the Information in Excel.
Do you had this Problem before? Or maybe know the answer anyway?

Would help me a lot!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was main change of the fund investment strategy. If the strategy of a fund changes, then the previous history is more or less useless for comparison reasons. In most cases, fund name and identifier changes. If you need the time series history before the change, you have to use a different field name. You have to ask your Bloomberg for the right field name.